# Knowing what rows were deleted when using 'delete duplicates' in excel

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet  with columns ranging from A to W and rows from 1 to 21,363. When I use the function 'delete duplicates' in excel filtering on all columns it removes 550 duplicates. But when I filter on just a couple of columns I get that it removed 627 duplicates. I know the difference between the deletes is due to criteria but I would like to review the deleted rows.

Is there some way I can see those deleted rows? I have used conditional formatting and I don't get the results I am looking for and I tried to combine all the columns into one cell and then use `countif` but the character string is longer than 255. Is there some way that I could see the deleted 550 or 627? Possibly using a macro that performs the same as 'delete duplicates' but instead moves them to another spreadsheet?

Please anything you can do to help would be greatly appreciated, as well my job kind of depends on me getting this figured out as I am trying out for this newly created position.

Comment: 1. Use a 2D array or dictionary to compute the 'duplicates' that would be removed. 2. Don't try out for a job where you rely on on-line forums to do your work for you.

Comment: you do realize that most people on here that post are working professionals who have come to a roadblock and are looking for help from others. Thank you for your help but i was not looking for job advice just a different thought on how to solve my issue. They approached me because I have more than average experience using excel (self taught mostly). I am trying to keep the job so I don't have to go back to menial work I was originally doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am just explaining with two columns A and B as an example,

- Select the range of columns A and B.
- In Home tab, click conditional formating --> new rule
- Select "use a formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter the below formula in the formula area.

  =COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,$A1,$B$1:$B$10,$B1)>1
- Select a format color and click ok
- Now you will have duplicate rows highlighted.

**Formula:** 
The above formula counts the number of duplicates within the row range 1-10. You could alter this based on your needs for multiple row and column ranges.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I'm guessing the $A$4 should be $A$1?

Comment: It's all good! I'm going to try it later when I'm at work. I'll let you know how it works! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: No worries. Vote up if you feel this helped you!!